# ASM is not loading object in class retransform but working fine with usual transform

Tags: java-bytecode-asm

I am trying to load some object through bytecode modification using `asm` bytecode instrumentation library.

I am retransforming the classes using `retransformClasses()` method.

I am loading the objects in this way :

```
super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);
super.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETFIELD, owner, name, desc);
super.visitMethodInsn(org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, 
                                    "com/coolcoder/MyClass", 
                                    "objectCheckTest",
                                    "(Ljava/lang/Object;)V");`
```

The problem is that I the objects are getting loaded using usual `tranform()` of `ClassTransformer` , but when I am using `Attach API`'s `retranformClasses()` , these objects are not getting loaded . Strange thing is that , I am not getting any bytecode error either.

Am I  doing something wrong ? or am I missing some intricate part regarding `retransform` ?

Comment: Are you sure the transformation is actually executed? I.e. can you add some debug output or something to make sure?

Comment: @AndreyBreslav : Yes , transformation is getting executed. I have added some debug statement in the objectCheckTest() to verify this , and they are getting executed.

Comment: @AndreyBreslav : I think the problem lies with `redefination`. Though I am not able to understand the problem fully , but I could see the classes in which I am doing these bytecode modifications , are gettting `redefined`. Any idea on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was be able to solve the issue , though I do not know why it happened in the first place.

(1) I was loading the object only on `PUTFIELD` or `PUTSTATIC` opcodes, i.e , when the object value is being set.

(2) Just after bytecode modification the class is getting redefined , as a result of which the code snippet did not work.

(3) Next time when the class loaded due to `redefinition` , the object is already being set , so it will not be called again.

(4) Now , when I checked for `GETFIELD` or `GETSTATIC` opcodes , i.e when the object's value is being retrieved and I loaded it , I was able to view its details.

The same approach which I mentioned above is working fine in usual `transformation` (i.e running with `premain`).

Any idea on this erratic behaviour of `redefinition` ?

Answer (score 0):

First, in manifest.mf file,**Can-Retransform-Classes** attribute should be **true**.

And your ClassFileTransformer instance should be add with the **true** value for parameter **canRetransform** in  method addTransformer .

Here is another additional  tips:

> If the transformer throws an exception (which it doesn't catch), subsequent transformers will still be called and the load, redefine or retransform will still be attempted. Thus, throwing an exception has the same effect as returning null. To prevent unexpected behavior when unchecked exceptions are generated in transformer code, a transformer can catch Throwable. If the transformer believes the classFileBuffer does not represent a validly formatted class file, it should throw an IllegalClassFormatException; while this has the same effect as returning null. it facilitates the logging or debugging of format corruptions.

from [java api docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html)

So, there maybe some uncatched exception which will be just ignored by the jvm arised.
You can put a try..catch

Please forgive my poor English ...